unable to post to the database properly
I am using material ui data grid to update cell in the grid on update. Here is the react code below
const processRowUpdate = (newRow) => {
            const updatedRow = {...newRow, isNew: false};
            setRows(rows.map((row) => (row.id === newRow.id ? updatedRow : row)));
            axios.post('http://localhost:3000/inventory', {updatedRow}, {
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                }
            })
                .then(response => console.log(response.data))
                .catch(error => console.error(error));
            return updatedRow;
        }
    ;

JSON before saving row:
{
  "inventory": [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "condition": "New",
      "brand": "Rolex",
      "model": "Submariner"
    },
    {
      "id": "2",
      "condition": "Pre-Owned",
      "brand": "Rolex",
      "model": "Cellini"
    }
  ]
}

JSON after saving:
{
  "inventory": [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "condition": "New",
      "brand": "Rolex",
      "model": "Submariner"
    },
    {
      "id": "2",
      "condition": "Pre-Owned",
      "brand": "Rolex",
      "model": "Cellini"
    },
    {
      "updatedRow": {
        "id": "1",
        "condition": "New",
        "brand": "Rolex",
        "model": "Explorer",
        "isNew": false
      },
      "id": "RQfGdm3"
    }
  ]
}

What should happen is after the row is updated and saved it should patch the oldROw with the newRow data. However it is giving me a random id and creating a nested json
